# C program for calculating alphabetical strings

Tags: c, loops, alphabetical

Task:

Create a function maxRepeatingLetter that receives a string and as a result returns the letter that is repeated the most times in the given string (if more than one letter meets the given condition, return the first letter of the English alphabet). It is assumed that there will be at least one letter in the string.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char maxRepeatingLetter(const char *s)
{
int i, max = 0, maxIndex = 0;
int letter[26] = {0}; 
const char *pom = s;
while (*pom != '\0') 
{
  if ((*pom >= 'a' && *pom <= 'z'))
  {
     letter[*pom - 97]++;
  }
  if (*pom >= 'A' && *pom <= 'Z')
  {
     letter[*pom - 65]++;
  }
 pom++; 
}
 
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
   if (letter[i] > max) 
   { 
    max =letter[i]; maxIndex = I;
   }
 return maxIndex + 65;
}

int main () 
{
 printf("Most repeating letter is: %c", 
 maxRepeatingLetter("input for letter to repeat"));
 return 0;
}
```

My current task is being able to explain the code above and how it works. And I need to input a minor change into it, for example, to add something to the code, or make it simpler. But not to lose the main functions the code has.

Is anyone willing to explain the code above in 2-3 lines? And if you could, assist me or hint me, or even show me, what changes to the code I could apply.

Comment: The best, and only, advice I can give is that you should take a large sheet of paper and trace the execution of the program line by line by line, making sure you update the values of each variable at each line. You'll learn far more that way than if someone explains the code to you.  I guarantee that if you do get an 'answer' explaining the code you will, within minutes, be asking for a different explanation, one you can understand better.

Comment: If it's your homework to try to understand this code, then I won't do it for you. However there are two things in the code I don't like: the usage of the number 65 and 97: 65 is the ASCII code of capital `"A"` and 97 of the small letter `"a"`. I would advise you to replace those entries (but I don't know the exact syntax, it's something like `(int)'A'` but I'm not sure of that). For the rest, you might follow Mark's advise.

Comment: jockowillick,  Range tests were done with `*pom >= 'a' && *pom <= 'z'`, so why was the subtraction done with 97 and not `'a'`?

Comment: @Dominique The syntax is `'A'`.  The cast in `(int)'A'` is redundant as `'A'` is an `int`.

Comment: Hints: research `toupper()`.  All ` - 65`,` - 97`, and ` + 65` are not needed if `int letter[26]` was larger.  Case detection not needed in the `while (*pom != '\0')` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you have to distinguish lowercase and uppercase and you can have only letters not symbols such as ? | ^ ! ecc... so I'll try to give you some advice:

1. Try to indent the code, it will be more readable to an external eye.
2. Using the variable `letter` is a good idea but i don't get the point of using `pom`.
3. If you can use use the function `strlen()` from the library `string.h`, otherwise implementing it by yourself could be a good exercise.
4. `letter[*pom - 97]++`, `letter[*pom - 65]++` and `maxIndex + 65` are dependant from the ASCII table, try `letter[*pom - 'a']++`, `letter[*pom - 'A']++` and `maxIndex + 'A'`.
5. The `for` loop doesn't work, you missed a brackets so the `if` isn't in the for.

The code explanation is pretty easy, first of all you use the array`letter` of 26 elements because in the alphabet we have 26 letters, so the i-th element correspond to the i-th letter of the alphabet.

You loop once on the string and save in the i-th element `letter` the number of occurrence of the i-th letter.

With the `if` in `for` loop you are simply finding the max in that array, once found it, you return the index of the max, the index is the letter occuring more often.

Sorry for my bad English tell me if you need more help.

Comment: Really simplified for my noobie brain. I understood the task much better now. Thank you for your time and your input. Cheers

Comment: OP's `while (*pom != '\0')` is much better than calling `strlen()`.  `strlen()` would only cause another pass through the string.

Answer (score 1):

It is very straightforward if you are looking for an explanation of the above code. I recommend using multiple prints to understand how things are happening. Here are my few tips.

1. function `maxRepeatingLetter()` is updating the counter table `letter[]` each time the character appears.
2. After that, the code tries to find the highest number in the counter table `letter[]`.